# What's the reason behind using routes file in modern frameworks?

Tags: php, laravel, symfony, model-view-controller, routes

In modern web frameworks (Laravel, Symfony, Silex, to name a few), there seems to be a pattern of using a `routes.php` file or similar to attach URIs to controllers. Laravel makes it a bit easier with an option to use PHP annotations.

But to me all this feels like a bit of a code repetition, and when you are creating/modifying controller logic, you have to keep routes file always at hand. Interestingly, there's a simpler way I saw in several old frameworks, and I used to use this in my old projects as well:

---

**Controller.** All classes in `src/controllers` folder (old way) or all classes in `YourApp\Controllers` namespace are being automatically mapped to the first part of the URL by adding "Controller" to it. Example: `/auth` gets mapped to `AuthController`, `/product/...` — to `ProductController`, and `/` — to default `IndexController`.

**Action.** Action is the second part of the URL, and it gets mapped to the method name. So, `/auth/login` will call `AuthController::loginAction()` method. If no second part provided, we try `indexAction()`. Don't want people to access some internal method? Don't make it public.

**Parameters.** Next parts of the URL are being mapped to the arguments of the method; if there are `Application` and/or `Request` type hintings in the argument list, they are skipped so they can be properly injected; we can access GET/POST variables as usual through Request.

Here's the full example, using all these features together:

```
URL: https://example.com/shop/category/computers?country=US&sort=brand

namespace MyApp\Controllers;

class ShopController extends BaseController {
    public function categoryAction(Application $app, Request $req, $category, $subcategory = null) {
        echo $category; // computers
        echo $subcategory; // null, it's optional here
        echo $req->get('country'); // US
        echo $req->get('sort'); // brand
    }
}
```

I'm sure it seems to lack some familiar features at first, but all features that I can think of could be easily added if needed — using attachable providers, connecting middlewares, branching controllers to subcontrollers, specifying HTTP methods, and even performing a bit of a pre-validation on the arguments. It's very flexible.

---

This approach would really speed up the routing creation and management. So besides having all the routes in one file (which is also not always true, considering various providers, using ->mount() in Silex or bundles in Symfony), what are the reasons modern frameworks seem to prefer this way of doing MVC routing over the simpler way I've described? What am I missing?

Comment: primarily opinion-based - Many good questions generate some degree of opinion based on expert experience, but answers to this question will tend to be almost entirely based on opinions, rather than facts, references, or specific expertise.

Comment: may be this article could help you. http://programmers.stackexchange.com/a/122198

Comment: @HimanshuRaval, thanks for the link, I've read an answer and a linked wikipedia article, but it seems to be describing benefits of having routes at all as opposed to using no rewrite engine whatsoever. All the benefits described there apply to both approaches here.

Comment: As a side note, you can override the RouteServiceProvider and do whatever you want to load your routes, you don't have to use the methods that are provided in the framework and you go the `oldschool` method you've outlined above.

Comment: some frameworks support `RESTful Resource Controllers` in which you have to map an URI to a controller and it automatically maps the methods. see [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/controllers#restful-resource-controllers) how laravel does it

Comment: I like that you can easily change the structure of your endpoints (e.g. for SEO or to be able to apply regular expressions on route names) if you have the urls separated from the method names (which is in fact one outcome of the routes file).

Comment: @herrjeh42, good points, but isn't it better while equally easier to change the method (via Quick Rename from IDE's refactoring tools), so that the method name is consistent with the route? (Which it's not in case of having route file and changing things). And I mentioned validating arguments with regular expressions already - we would have no problem implementing this logic inside the method, using the methods from the base controller class.

Comment: maybe I just need some specific examples to understand the context (about SEO for instance)

Comment: @Ohgodwhy, @ CerlinBoss - interesting points, thanks. So Laravel **does** do it in some specific cases. And it provides a way to override the defaults. Good to know.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'll speak here from Symfony/Silex perspective:

1. **Decoupling.** `routes.php` provide separation of URL mapping and controllers. Do you need to add or change URL? You go straight to `routes.php`. Very handy if you want to change a lot of them.
2. **Flexibility.** Generally, `routes.php` is a bit more flexible approach. SEO might go crazy and might require you to have route like `/shop_{shopName}/{categoryName}/someStaticKeyword/{anotherVar}`. With `routes.php` you can easily map this to your code, but this might become a problem if your routes are directly mapped to the code. Even more, you can have **this only** controller, you don't need to write controllers for each slash part. You can even have different controllers handling the same URL with different variable parts, for example `/blog/[\d]+` or `/blog/[a-z-]+` being handled by different controllers (one might generate redirect to another). You might never need to do something like this, but this is just a demonstration of flexibility of this approach - with it anything is possible.
3. **Validation.** Another thing to consider is that `routes.php` provide simple means of validation via `->assert` method. That is, `routes.php` does not only map URLs to controller methods, but also ensure that these URLs match specific requirements, and you don't have to do this in code (which in most scenarios would take a bit more code to write). Also, you can create default asserts for some variables, for instance, you may ensure that `{page}` or `{userId}` are always `\d+`, single line in `routes.php` that would take care of all usages of `{page}` or `{userId}`.
4. **URL Generation.** One more feature of `routes.php` is url generation. You can assign any route any name (via `->bind()` method) and then generate URLs based on that name, and providing variables for parts of URL that change. And once we have this system and use URL generator throughout our code we can change URLs as much as we want, but we won't have any need to edit anything but `routes.php`. And once again - these are flexible names, that you won't have to change everywhere throughout your project once URL has changed and you are not limited choosing the name. It might be much shorter than the URL, or a bit more verbose.
5. **Maintainability.** Say, you might want to change some urls (as in example above - from `/blog/[\d+]` to `/blog/[a-z-]+`. Also, you might want to keep both of them for some time, and make old one redirect to the new one). With `routes.php` you simply add a new line and add a todo memo to remove it in some time if you want to remove it later.

Sure, all of this might be achieved with any aproach. But would that be this simple, flexible, transparent and compact as this approach?

Comment: That makes a lot of sense, well done. Special thanks for specific examples, that's what I needed. Some of them feel a bit far-fetched though (like, why would you need separate controllers for `/blog/[\d]+` and `/blog/[a-z-]+`, that doesn't really make sense), but overall, I'm sold on this. URL generation is also what I didn't think of - no IDE currently can replace `"/auth/signin"` with `"/auth/login"` in redirect argument while refactoring the method name. Nice answer.

Comment: Explained a bit about that url. One might return redirect to the other (SEO might want this change and behavior).

Comment: So, `/blog/[\d]+` would be the old route, and `/blog/[a-z-]+` would be the new route, but both are there for backwards compatibility. And instead of having a method with redirect (or controllers in some cases just for this purpose), I just have one line in routes.php. Yep, sounds good.

Answer (score 3):

Just as note, the standard edition of Symfony is shipped with SensioFrameworkExtraBundle, that allows to use annotations instead of file-based declaration:

```
/**
 * @Route("/")
 */
public function indexAction()
{
    // ...
}
```

In the same manner, you can set the prefix for the whole controller file:

```
/**
 * @Route("/blog")
 */
class PostController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * @Route("/{id}")
     */
    public function showAction($id)
    {
    }
}
```

Still, we have to declare it. I think the main reason is that routing requirements are heavily influenced by SEO optimizations. For anything that faces the public you want some keyword-rich URL. The "public" logic organization may also be different, you may have only one controller to deliver all your static pages, still you want those to be /contact, /about...

In some domains, routes can be inferred with conventions. If you create a REST API using FosRestBundle, it will auto-generate routes based on your controllers/actions names on the ressource approach. In general I think the FosRestBundle got a lot of things in their approach, you can easily parse and validate query parameters at the same time:

```
class FooController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * This action route will be /foo/articles, GET method only
     *
     * @QueryParam(name="val", default="75 %%")
     */
    public function getArticlesAction(ParamFetcher $paramFetcher)
    {
        ...
    }
```

Comment: Can you please provide a real-life example of keyword-rich URL that would look ugly as a method name (considering we can easily turn underscores to camel case if we want)? As for static pages, yes, that sounds pretty valid. I remember I did it using `AboutController extends StaticController`, but I would still end up with empty classes for every such route. So that's a good one.

Comment: On one website I worked on the URL would look like `/catalog/sport/combat/12`, having keywords from the parent category and the theme in the URL. Each of those are dynamic, we have only one Symfony controller action with a route such as  `/catalog/{catalog}/{theme}/{id} ̀

Comment: Well, this is a case of dynamically loaded action. If it were `/cat/alog/...`, you wouldn't have any problem, because the rest you would get as arguments and load from database. But dynamic action is also easily achievable through catch-all method __call in CatalogController. I was actually thinking you were referring to something like /catalog/i_love_sport_very_much for SEO, but which would absolutely need to go to CatalogController::sportAction (not dynamic load, but specific controller), but I'm wondering whether it's such a wide-spread practice in reality, or just theorizing.

Answer (score 1):

I always prefer having the routes in a config file rather than using annotations because, firstly, I feel it's more maintainable and easier to have an oversight. It's easier to ensure that you don't have any conflicting routes when you can see them all together.

Additionally, it's theoretically faster. Annotations require reflection, where the application needs to scan the file system and parse each controller to collect the set of routes.

Comment: Interestingly, the approach I described brings those benefits even more effectively. If you have class and method names matching controller and action names, you are sure that they don't conflict with each other. The speed is even better here as well: instead of adding routes and having them somewhere, you just add 'Controller' and 'Action' to controller and action name, and do $controller::$action(). If you fail, that's 404.

Comment: And I know that, at least in Silex, when you need to mount controller collection to the path, you have to instantiate a new controller class and call ->__construct() and ->connect(). On all the controller classes that may not even be used in serving this request.

Comment: Having class and method names matching your controller action names only works if you have extremely simple routes. If, for example, you have an articles section on your site and you have editor-submitted content and user-submitted content, and you want them both to appear prefixed with /articles, how would you do this? And if you want your controllers to be called UserArticlesController and EditorArticlesController I doubt you want "userarticles" and "editorarticles" to appear in your URL.

Comment: Sorry, not following. How would having route file have this problem solved?

Comment: Because then I can manually define that this route should go to this controller and action.

Comment: So, you would set route /articles/{whatever} to go to ArticlesController? But how would you differentiate between editor-submitted and user-submitted articles? Hard to understand out of context.

Comment: For example, something like /articles/{category}/{id} and /articles/community/{category}/{id}

Comment: Ah, got it. Well, for dynamic value in place of action we can use `__call()`. So, to build the structure you described, one ArticleController is enough, consisting of two methods: communityAction($category, $id) matching /articles/community/{category}/{id} and __call() as a fallback for /articles/{category}/{id}. Does it make sense?

Answer (score 0):

The reason is probably maintainability for the long term. It doesn't matter how the routes are set up but generally, Laravel as a framework focuses on the simplicity and the small things that make the framework great. As long as it is easy to use for the user (web developer in this case), the goal is reached.

You can use a different name for the routes.php file and also use multiple route files, if you have a lot of routes in your application.

You can try and rethink the whole concept to improve it but I don't think that Laravel's routes need really a big change to make it even easier. It's already simple. Maybe it will be changed for the better in the future but for now, I think it's fine.

Comment: How is it simpler, if it needs more work? Having route file versus ditching it completely.

Comment: The idea you presented in your post seems complicated for beginners and people have to really understand how it works and remind themselves from time to time just so they can remember the route they were looking for. That sounds like more mental complexity rather than having files where you can check what you need or use the php artisan routes:list command for that. Also, where's the freedom in custom stuff?

Comment: Hmm, yeah, that seems reasonable. Of course, frameworks still force some definitions and ideas on users in some places, but any work in the direction of allowing for customization and more leeway is always welcomed, sure. Thanks for the hint.

Comment: I wanted to know if there are some _technical_ disadvantages to the idea I described over the traditional way, but at least I have one possible reason of why frameworks may prefer to stick to routing files.